# Converting Image-->Sound--->Record sound---->Image

Tags: java, image, audio, javasound

I am creating a program which does following:

1. Convert an Image(png) to Sound(wav).
2. Playing and recording that Sound.
3. Reproducing the Image from Sound.

The program uses only Red(from RGB) values of image and put them in a wave file like this:

Consider the following words as Red pixel values in image:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4

B1 B2 B3 B4

C1 C2 C3 C4       (I am using a square image)

D1 D2 D3 D4
```

it puts them in wave file like this:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4 C1 C2 C3 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4
```

Problem is when sound plays and i record it then the starting time and ending time of recording need to be exactly same as of the sound produced by program(which is never possible) otherwise pixels displace like:

```
XX XX A1 A2

A3 A4 B1 B2

B3 B4 C1 C2

C3 C4 D1 D2
```

You get the idea right!!

Here's the partial code I am using to convert Image to Sound:

```
imgBuffer = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Sound_To_Image.png"));
int[][][] pixels = new int[width][height][3];
LOOP
(
c = new Color(imgBuffer.getRGB(i,j));
pixels[i][j][0] = c.getRed();
)
```

//--------------CREATING LONG 1D ARRAY FROM 2D ARRAY

```
byte buf[]=new byte[width*height+1];
LOOP
(
buf[ptr]=(byte)(pixels[x][y][0]);
)

ByteArrayInputStream bais =new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(20000f, 8, 1, true, false);
File file = new File("D:\\Image_To_Sound.wav");
long length = (long)(buf.length / format.getFrameSize());
AudioInputStream audioInputStreamTemp = new AudioInputStream(bais, format, length);
AudioSystem.write(audioInputStreamTemp, Type.WAVE, file);
```

And the code for sound to image is:

```
AudioInputStream ais=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(wavFile);
byte[] data=new byte[ais.available()];
ais.read(data);
```

//----------------ONE SIDE FOR PRODUCING SQUARE IMAGE AND IMAGE WRITING

```
int oneSide = (int)Math.ceil(Math.sqrt((double)data.length));
int temp = data.length;
System.out.println("lnght="+data.length+"and sqr="+oneSide*oneSide);
BufferedImage img= new BufferedImage(oneSide, oneSide, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

LOOP
(
Color c2=new Color(Math.abs(data[ptr]),0, 0 );
img.setRGB(i, j, c2.getRGB());
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Am stuck at this for over a month.

Comment: *"you get the idea right!!"*  Not really.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't understand the question!

It seems to have something to do with managing audio in real time, so here's a link to some general background on "real time" issues with Java audio. Maybe it will help. http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx?c=icmc;idno=bbp2372.2007.131 "Real Time Low Latency Audio Processing in Java".